# How to restore minimized custom form during debug in Pega

Tags: c#, .net, rpa, pega, rda

When I minimize a custom windows form in Pega during the debug, it sometimes gets stuck in the bottom taskbar. When this happens I have to stop the entire run. It's very cumbersome and slows down the development process immensely. Can anyone help me to a resolution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you debug via Tracer using breakpoints, then It's o'key that your application freezes. You should just press "Play" on the Tracer window to release your application.